# Docker can't find my .java files in an IntelliJ project setup

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I have a Java project that I made on IntelliJ. [The file structure, which is simply the default set by IntelliJ, looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wLUT.png)

I want to build a Docker image for the entire project (the Main class takes input from the driver-info.txt file in the root folder), and push it to Docker Hub.

I created a Dockerfile with no file extension in the root folder, and inside it I have pasted (this came directly from my course material):

```
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN javac *.java
CMD java Main
```

Then I went to the command terminal and cd to the root directory of this project (i.e. C:\Users\User-PC\IdeaProjects\Task_11_Capstone>). There I typed in (also directly pasted from my course material):

```
docker build -t java-app ./
```

It builds step 1 and 2, but gives an error on step 3, saying:

```
=> ERROR [4/4] RUN javac *.java                                                                                   0.4s
------
 > [4/4] RUN javac *.java:
#8 0.363 error: file not found: *.java
#8 0.363 Usage: javac <options> <source files>
#8 0.363 use --help for a list of possible options
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c javac *.java]: exit code: 2
```

I believe there is an issue with Docker finding my java files in the src/com/company folder (see image I shared regarding the project file structure). I have tried changing the path name, and I have tried using the fully qualified name, based on other articles on StackOverflow. But they all give me the same error message.

I have also tried locating the Dockerfile *inside* the src/com.company folder next to the other classes. But then it refactors the Dockerfile "COPY" statement to say `COPY ../../.. /app`. Which I think is right because I do want to copy all the items including the .txt files in the root folder into my image.

I then cd to the folder where the Dockerfile is now located (i.e. C:\Users\User-PC\IdeaProjects\Task_11_Capstone\src\com\company) to build the image. Is this correct or should I stay in the project root folder? Anyhow, doing it this way *does* allow me to successfully build the image. (I think - [this is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbxEr.png)).

However, when it comes time to run the image, I get stuck again. I type the following in the command line (taken directly from my course material):

```
docker run java-app
```

And it gives me this error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

In other words, if if I put the Dockerfile right where the java files are, it still can't seem to find them.

I have tried Docker Hub forum, Stackoverflow, have had over 10 back and forth emails with IntelliJ support, and have screenshared with my course mentor, we just can't figure out why it won't run. I've also uninstalled Docker and reinstalled it, and created a version of my project without the com.company package.

As a side, I have successfully managed to build, run and push other Docker images, notably a website and a simple java programme. However it is only when trying to do it in my project in IntelliJ that it is giving me these issues. It may be worth noting that this is also a Git repository which is connected to GitHub.

Any ideas for what I could try next?

Comment: I think you are mixing up things, and you lack some basics. You have to understand what packages are for xample, and that `com.company.Main` is something different than a class named `Main`. It also implies that you do not understand what the classpath is. So, for me, it sounds like you should first learn all such java basics, before adding that additional complexity of a docker image.

Comment: do you actually have a file with name * ? javac *.java is looking for a file called *.java, not 'all files with extension .java'

Comment: The other part: any realistic real world project should be build just using `javac *.java` ... you would rather be looking at using a tool like gradle or maven. And such tools often have support to turn deliveries into docker images, just saying. You are trying to reinvent wheels here ...

Comment: And note: if you go with your approach, do it without docker first. Meaning: just write a SHELL script to run javac and run your code. As said: you get THOSE basic command line things already wrong. There is no point in asking "how do I juggle while riding the bicycle" ... when already the juggling alone gives you trouble.

Comment: Hi @Stultuske oh I see, I thought that using * is like a placeholder for all .java files. I have about 5 files with .java extensions but they all have different names. Should they be listed one by one when compiling?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the RUN and CMD command on the Dockerfile to

```
RUN javac com/comapny/*.java
CMD java -cp . com.company.Main
```

I'm assuming that the Main is under the package `com.company`